# Is it possible to return a child node and a parent node with JSON PATH in the same queries in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

Suppose that we have this JSON:

```
{
  "table" : 
    [
        {
            "A": "A1",
            "B":
            {  
                "BA":"BA1",
                "BB":"BB1"
            }
        },
        {
            "A": "A2",
            "B":
            {  
                "BA":"BA2",
                "BB":"BB2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With ONLY ONE query I want to return a set of data composed by 2 type of data: "A" and "BA". For example I can make a request : `$.table[<filter>].[A,B.BA]`  it doesn't work, but it's the idea. I want to return the value of the parent A and the child BA in ONLY one query. Firstly is it possible and secondly if yes, how ?

Comment: if you have a proper defined structure of your JSON, then you can make a function fo returning the value, based on your specified requirement, what I can understand is you want to match the keys found in your JSON

Comment: Not necessarily the key, I want to return two information which isn't in the same order, by order I mean that A and B are parent and AB and BB are children it's not the same order. But for example if I had C as parent so in the same order than A and B, and I want not the request to return the value of C and the value of BA, how can I do that ? There is the point. Tell me if I'm not clear in my explanation please

Comment: For example again, I want the value of table[0].A and table[1].B.AB in only ONE request, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that's impossible to retrieve precisely multiple attribute from a JSON Path request. But in certain case, we can do it... But these case are rare and it's risky to use this type of request.
SO there is another way to query JSON objet: JMESPATH. It's FAR better and simplier, and most importantly it solve the problem of retrieving multiple attribute, for my problem the syntax would be: `table[<filter>].[A,B.BA]` (as I wanted in the initial post). Here's some links:
 - install it: [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jmespath)
 - tutorial/official website: [website](http://jmespath.org/)